# Update date with date field in another table

Tags: marketing-cloud, date, sql, inner-join

I'm wanting to update the date field in one table with the date from another table. Below is an example snippet of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
ln.[DateEntered] AS 'acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c]'
FROM
[Car Loan - Update EntryDate] ln
INNER JOIN [Account_Salesforce] acc
```

Essentially I want to update the DateEntered field from the Car Loan - Update EntryDate table with the date in the Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c field in the Account_Salesforce table.

If someone could advise on how I could accomplish this that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What missing is the common column (key) between `[Car Loan - Update EntryDate]` and `[Account_Salesforce]`.

Assuming the have the column , `Car_Type__c` in common:

```
ln.[DateEntered] AS 'acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c]'
FROM
[Car Loan - Update EntryDate] ln
INNER JOIN [Account_Salesforce] acc 
ON ln.Car_Type__c = acc.Car_Type__c
```

Hope this helps